# Split String with a word delimiter into array in bash

Tags: string, bash, split

I have a string like below:

> `dn: uid=svc_ddvportal2ssh,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=tenant,dc=ycsdev,dc=io cn: svc_ddvportal2ssh svc_ddvportal2ssh krbpasswordexpiration: 20180607182429Z dn: uid=svc_ddvrundeckdeploy,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=tenant,dc=ycsdev,dc=io cn: svc_ddvrundeckdeploy svc_ddvrundeckdeploy krbpasswordexpiration: 20180607182430Z dn: uid=svc_bo2ansible_mon,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=tenant,dc=ycsdev,dc=io cn: svc_bo2ansible_mon svc_bo2ansible_mon krbpasswordexpiration: 20990101200000Z`

wanted to extract like below into array a

```
a[0] = dn: uid=svc_bo2icinga2ipa,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=tenant,dc=ycsdev,dc=io cn: svc_bo2icinga2ipa svc_bo2icinga2ipa krbpasswordexpiration: 20180119194104Z
a[1] = dn: uid=svc_ddvrundeckdeploy,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=tenant,dc=ycsdev,dc=io cn: svc_ddvrundeckdeploy svc_ddvrundeckdeploy krbpasswordexpiration: 20180607182430Z
a[2] = uid=svc_bo2ansible_mon,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=tenant,dc=ycsdev,dc=io cn: svc_bo2ansible_mon svc_bo2ansible_mon krbpasswordexpiration: 20990101200000Z
```

I tried using `IFS` delimitor but not succeeded. Please someone help me into this

Comment: Which word, specifically, is the delimiter? Can you build shorter / easier to read sample data that makes the logic you want more obvious? (The [mcve] rules don't just apply to code).

Comment: Why is there no `dn:` prefix on the `a[2]` value?

Comment: I have this suspicion that the line feeds aren't suppose to exist in the input string.

Comment: @JNevill, ...what line feeds? I don't see any in the question's text; it's just in single backticks to allow line wrapping to be done by the browser, so folks can actually read the input data without scrolling left-to-right.

Comment: a[2] also consists of dn element. Typo error.

Answer (score 2):

Build your array with GNU sed:

```
mapfile -t a < <(sed -r 's/ .{14}Z /&\n/g' file)
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Maybe add a `readarray` or `mapfile` consuming the output of that `sed` command, since the OP wants to populate an array?

Comment: BTW, I'm curious which of us is right wrt. guessing the OP's intended delimiter -- you're stopping after `Z`s, I'm starting at a `dn:`. (BTW, maybe change it from `.{14}` to `[[:digit:]]{14}`?)

Answer (score 1):

This is doable, yes. If you don't mind reversing the array's order, the easiest approach would look something like:

```
s='dn: uid=svc_ddvportal2ssh,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=tenant,dc=ycsdev,dc=io cn: svc_ddvportal2ssh svc_ddvportal2ssh krbpasswordexpiration: 20180607182429Z dn: uid=svc_ddvrundeckdeploy,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=tenant,dc=ycsdev,dc=io cn: svc_ddvrundeckdeploy svc_ddvrundeckdeploy krbpasswordexpiration: 20180607182430Z dn: uid=svc_bo2ansible_mon,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=tenant,dc=ycsdev,dc=io cn: svc_bo2ansible_mon svc_bo2ansible_mon krbpasswordexpiration: 20990101200000Z'

while [[ $s =~ (.*)(dn: .*) ]]; do
  results+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" )
  s=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
done
declare -p results # print the resulting array
```

...which emits as output (with line breaks added for readability):

```
declare -a results='(
  [0]="dn: uid=svc_bo2ansible_mon,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=tenant,dc=ycsdev,dc=io cn: svc_bo2ansible_mon svc_bo2ansible_mon krbpasswordexpiration: 20990101200000Z"
  [1]="dn: uid=svc_ddvrundeckdeploy,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=tenant,dc=ycsdev,dc=io cn: svc_ddvrundeckdeploy svc_ddvrundeckdeploy krbpasswordexpiration: 20180607182430Z "
  [2]="dn: uid=svc_ddvportal2ssh,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=tenant,dc=ycsdev,dc=io cn: svc_ddvportal2ssh svc_ddvportal2ssh krbpasswordexpiration: 20180607182429Z "
)'
```

If by contrast you're willing to eat a performance penalty to retain the original ordering, change `results+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" )` to `results=( "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${results[@]}" )`.

---

What we're doing here is matching the sequences from the back to the front (since bash doesn't have non-greedy regular expressions, the first `.*` matches everything to the *last* `dn:`).